# Keep values of between two columns based on third column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns, A, B and C. I want to create a fourth column D that contains values of A or B, based on the value of C. For example:

```
   A   B   C   D 
0  1   2   1   1
1  2   3   0   3
2  3   4   0   4
3  4   5   1   4
```

In the above example, column D takes the value of column A if the value of C is 1 and the value of column B if the value of C is 0. Is there an elegant way to do it in Pandas? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***`pandas`***
In consideration of the OP's request

> Is there an elegant way to do it in Pandas?

*my opinion of elegance*
and idiomatic pure `pandas`
[**`assign`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) + [**`pd.Series.where`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html)

```
df.assign(D=df.A.where(df.C, df.B))

   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  1  1
1  2  3  0  3
2  3  4  0  4
3  4  5  1  4
```

---

***response to comment***

> how would you modify the pandas answer if instead of 0, 1 in column C you had A, B?

```
df.assign(D=df.lookup(df.index, df.C))

   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  A  1
1  2  3  B  3
2  3  4  B  4
3  4  5  A  4
```

Comment: how would you modify the pandas answer if instead of 0, 1 in column C you had A, B?

Answer (score 10):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  2  3  0
2  3  4  0
3  4  5  1

In [21]: df['D'] = np.where(df.C, df.A, df.B)

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  1  1
1  2  3  0  3
2  3  4  0  4
3  4  5  1  4
```